# Process address is different in .NET Framework and .NET core

Tags: c#, .net-core, kernel32

I have an application developed in the .NET Framework and now I am updating it to .NET CORE, and in .NET CORE the GetProcAddress method of kernel32.dll (DllImportAttribute) gets a different process address than the same application in the .NET Framework, because it happens this if it is exactly the same code? How can I get .NET CORE to return the same address for that process as .NET Framework?

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procName);

private static void GetProcess()
{
   IntPtr mh = Kernel32.GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll");
   if (mh != IntPtr.Zero)
   {
      IntPtr load_library_w = Kernel32.GetProcAddress(mh, "LoadLibraryW");               
   }
}
```

- **NET Framework process adress (load_library_w):** 0x777c1620
- **NET CORE process adress (load_library_w):** 0x00007ff887a5fe80

**I would like to know how I can get the same memory address as in the .NET Framework.**

Comment: Please avoid relying on a constant process address. It could be randomized as a security feature. With that said, I believe you can specify the preferred address in project settings.

Comment: For starters, by either compiling the .NET Core project as 32-bit or the .NET Framework project as 64-bit. .NET Framework defaults to 32-bit ("Any CPU" with "Prefer 32-bit" checked); .NET Core does not. Per Theroat, however, if ASLR (address space layout randomization) is applied, the address will vary from process to process and from run to run.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Effectively, compiling the .NET CORE project to 32-bit has solved my problem, thanks.